# Java 11+ still cross platform?

Tags: java, jvm, cross-platform, java-11

how could i produce a cross platform jar file built with jdk 11+? as i understood from articles on the internet i have to build a specific jre for each platform as there is no standard jre for java 11 and the user can't download a jre to run the jar file that he want. If that is true how should java be a cross platform language by that? and how java will be different from other languages that could be compiled to binary for each platform? and why we can't compile java directly to the binary code instead of building a jvm for each platform?
another small question could jlink build a 32 and 64 jre or it could just build for one of them?

Comment: You can still create a jar as before. There is no JRE *without a JDK* from Oracle, but there are other sites offering JREs. Besides that, nobody gets hurt when downloading a JDK instead of a JRE.

Comment: Even if you solution will work by downloading jre from other sites, I want to know how openjdk project and oracle want the user to do. It's just unbelivable that they should download jdk. And if that is true many of jre features will not be avilable such as java icon in the cpanel, autorun to jar files, small space taken on the disk and many more.

Comment: Your first question is how to produce a cross platform jar file and the answer is, the same way as before. To a Java application, your rants about JDK vs JRE are irrelevant. Java still is available to at least as many platforms as before. Whether there is a Java Control Panel in the target environment, is irrelevant to the application. Neither will anyone miss crapware like the Ask toolbar. Starting jar files via double click still is possible. Not that this was a crucial feature.